# Can I write directive that is decoupled from the main app?

Tags: angularjs, web

I am starting to write a little library that uses angular.  I want to write a directive that is not coupled to the first app that is initialized.  I want to write a directive that somebody would add to their app and it would just work.

Instead of:

```
angular.module('realEstateApp', []);
   angular.module('realEstateApp').directive(etc);
```

Just use:

```
   angular.directive(etc)
```

If I can't do this, do you have some workaround to give me?

Comment: why you don't want to prefer a directive syntax like app.directive?

Comment: I read somewhere that this is a bad practice to imply the module to the directive. because thats makes variable mess. like if I have somewhere else the same name of variable,one will override other

Comment: @Daffa In order to avoid that, you should always define your modules and dependencies with a custom prefix.

Comment: @taxicala yes but if I have another syntax, why messing it up with prefix?

Comment: @Daffa it is not messing up, even Angular docs tell you that you should always use prefixes :)

Comment: @taxicala thank you but I prefer it my way :)

Comment: @Daffa do you want to have your directive nature should be override? means any one can override its nature..

Comment: @pankajparkar I didn't understand the question, that way it would't be override because I only declare on directives in one place

Comment: I'm asking that do you want to override the behaviour of directive.. do look at this http://plnkr.co/edit/FSN6p58vdeMHEy6PiZCe?p=preview with directive initialization I defined its default behaviour..but other could override that behaviour just by adding `fn` again

Comment: no I don't want to override my behaviour, I define the func near the directive so it woudnt be override

Comment: @Daffa sorry for my misunderstanding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular directives need always to live within a module. What you have to do is define a module and then use it as a dependency in other modules. People will have to add Your module as a dependency to theyr module:

```
angular.module('myDirectiveModule', []);
angular.module('myDirectiveModule').directive(etc);
```

Then share your module, and people will have to do (after including your script):

```
angular.module('myModule', ["myDirectiveModule"]);
```